# Comparing datetime objects by date only

Tags: python, date, python-2.7, datetime

I have two `datetime` objects having same day, month and year, say:

```
test_date = datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 25, 11, 57, 56)
```

(above date is created like `datetime.utcfromtimestamp(utc_timestamp)`) and

```
now_date  = datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 25, 12, 40, 19, 705355)
```

(above date is created like `datetime.now()`). When I say

```
now_date==test_date
```

I get `False` when it should be `True`. How can I compare correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are currently comparing the whole `datetime` object, *including the time* (which doesn't match). Instead, just compare the [`date`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.date) part:

```
>>> now_date.date() == test_date.date()
True
```

Answer (score 2):

Since, you just want to compare the dates and not the time, you need to convert these to `datetime.date` objects which strip out the time related information.

```
In [1]: import datetime

In [2]: test_date = datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 25, 11, 57, 56)

In [3]: now_date = datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 25, 12, 40, 19, 705355)

In [4]: now_date == test_date
Out[4]: False

In [5]: test_date = test_date.date()

In [6]: test_date
Out[6]: datetime.date(2014, 4, 25)

In [7]: now_date = now_date.date()

In [8]: now_date
Out[8]: datetime.date(2014, 4, 25)

In [9]: now_date == test_date
Out[9]: True
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to compare day, month and year, you may just try:

```
now_date.strftime('%Y%m%d')==test_date.strftime('%Y%m%d')
```

Using this method, you can also specify other attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Simple function

```py
def date_extracter(string):
    day = re.search('\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}', string)
    date = datetime.datetime.strptime(day.group(), '%Y-%m-%d').date()
    return date
```