# convert a full string type time into datetime type - Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, python-datetime

I have a unicode string  `u'May 12, 2014 8:00:40 PM'` and I want to convert it into a date time object but I dont want time stamp, only date.

output should be `2014/5/12` or `2014/05/12`

I tried to use strptime but it didn't help me. may be I'm missing something else?

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/_strptime.pyc in _strptime(data_string, format)
    326     if len(data_string) != found.end():
    327         raise ValueError("unconverted data remains: %s" %
--> 328                           data_string[found.end():])
    329 
    330     year = None

ValueError: unconverted data remains:   1:33PM
```

I've already seen these threads

[Converting string into datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime)

[convert string to date type python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15557828/convert-string-to-date-type-python)

[Convert string into Date type on Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9504356/convert-string-into-date-type-on-python)

Comment: *I tried to use strptime but it didn't help me*. **How** did it not help you? What errors did you get, or how was the output not what you wanted?

Comment: You've *"seen these threads"*. What, if anything, did you learn from them? What do you still want to know? Have you read [the `datetime` docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html)? You might find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23293697/comparing-datetime-objects-by-date-only/23293996#23293996) useful.

Comment: You want to slice the input string to not include the timestamp, *or* parse the time portion as well. `strptime()` expects to parse *all of the input string*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`datetime.datetime.strptime()` expects to parse *all* of the input string. If you pass in `u'May 12, 2014 8:00:40 PM'`, you'll need to account for all characters.

Either split off the time portion, or parse the time portion as well, then ignore that part by calling `.date()` on the resulting `datetime.datetime()` object.

It's easier to just include the time:

```
dateobj = datetime.datetime.strptime(inputstring, '%B %d, %Y %I:%M:%S %p').date()
```

This gives you a `datetime.date()` object for *just* the date portion of the string.

Cutting of the time portion can be done with a `str.rsplit()` call, limited to 2 splits:

```
dateobj = datetime.datetime.strptime(inputstring.rsplit(None, 2)[0], '%B %d, %Y').date()
```

I've called `.date()` here as well.

Demo:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> inputstring = u'May 12, 2014 8:00:40 PM'
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime(inputstring, '%B %d, %Y %I:%M:%S %p').date()
datetime.date(2014, 5, 12)
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime(inputstring.rsplit(None, 2)[0], '%B %d, %Y').date()
datetime.date(2014, 5, 12)
```

Comment: @user3628682: then include the comma; I've done so now.

Comment: @user3628682: perhaps; here `%b` works (`May` is abbreviated to `May`), but `%B` is for full month names, `%b` for abbreviated months. Look at other examples; if you see `Mar 12, 2014` you need to use `%b`, if it uses `March 12, 2014`, you need to use `%B`.

Comment: @user3628682: No. You can't delete it because it has an upvoted answer now, anyway. And there are two duplicate *votes* on your post, it hasn't yet been put on hold; others would have to agree that it is a dupe. And last but not least, duplicate posts serve as sign-posts; it your post *is* closed as a dupe, then people using search keywords that point to your post can then find a canonical post from there.